# namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required

Tags: r, namespaces, rlang

I'm trying to install the 'lifecycle' package but rlangs is required.

Upon typing install.packages('lifecyle') I get the error that I'm importing a rlangs package which is newer than required ('rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required).

> - installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
>   ** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>   Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
>   **namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required**
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
> - removing 'C:/Users/user/R/library/lifecycle' In R CMD INSTALL
>   Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘lifecycle’
>   had non-zero exit status

I've already uninstalled rlangs and reinstalled it on its own, but it still not working.

Not sure if it helps, but I get the following message beforehand:

> There are binary versions available but the source versions are
> later:
> rlang - binary: 0.4.5 - source: 0.4.10 - needs_compilation: TRUE
> lifecycle - binary: 0.2.0 - source: 1.0.0 - needs_compilation: FALSE

This error makes little sense and differs from others posts with this kind of error.

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the output of `packageVersion("rlang")` after making `install.packages("rlang")`?

Comment: Sure! It's  packageVersion("rlang") [1] ‘0.4.5’. If it helps, I've updated my post with more information on the message upon installing "lifecycle".

Comment: Thanks, maybe you could try installing via github `devtools::install_github("r-lib/rlang", build_vignettes = TRUE)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: your version is not newer, it's older. `0.4.5` < `0.4.10`.

The issue is that for whatever reason the binary version you have access to is of version 0.4.5, but the source version (which needs compiling) is of version 0.4.10.

I believe the simplest solution would be downloading the source package and installing it as source.

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Now, if you don't want the trouble, I belive another possible solution would be updating your R version, which will in turn update the binary versions available for most packages.

Comment: Your solution returned a message that my RStudio was out of date. I've updated it and everything worked. Thanks!

Comment: @eduardokapp the path needs updating to https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz

Comment: I tried your solution and I got the message:
"packages/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status".
I guess this means whatever I was doing was not successful.
What gives?

Comment: @FaustinGashakamba it's hard to tell with that much information. Consider searching for that error message here in SO.

Comment: how is 10 (ten) older than 5 (five)?

Comment: the solution did not work for me: *** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/rlang'
* restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/rlang'

Comment: Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\library\00LOCK-rlang\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\library\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/xxxxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/zzzzzzz/downloaded_packages/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Apologies, I had to split the error message above due to the char limitation

Answer (score 15):

You should try removing `remove.packages("rlang")` then `install.packages("rlang")`

Comment: This worked for me but I had to replace remove.packages(rlang) with remove.packages("rlang")

Comment: Removing the package is overkill. It works, but that's because removal does the real need: detaching the package and unloading the shared library (`rlang.dll`). This can normally be done with something like `detach("package:rlang", unload=TRUE)` (assuming no other packages are depending on it.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but it worked for me, close all files in rstudio editor and run in the console:

`install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")`

Comment: Additionally recommended - just install the latest rlang `install.packages("rlang")` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

RStudio needs rlang and maybe other package to do the R code diagnostics. Hence it loads it whenever the global option `R diagnositics` is checked. Try to uncheck it, restart the R session:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and when I tried to update the rlang package, it told me that rlang could not be unloaded as it was required by something else (I presume when you try to update, the package gets unloaded and then the latest version gets loaded).
After coming to this question and reading some answers, I saw that I should move to the latest version in R Studio Cloud -
[Image with arrow indicating how to move to the latest version in R Studio Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdZQi.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).