# namespace 'rlang' 0.4.9 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required

Tags: r, rlang

I'm setting up my R environment. I got the following error:

```
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.9 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing '/exports/cmvm/eddie/eb/groups/prendergast_grp/Rongrong/Rlib40/lifecycle'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/Rtmp47QJxw/downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages("lifecycle") :
  installation of package 'lifecycle' had non-zero exit status
> packageVersion("rlang")
[1] '0.4.10'
```

And I checked my rlang version, it is already 0.4.10 but I still got the error that 'rlang 0.4.9 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required'. Can anyone help with this problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you just updated rlang package maybe restarting your R session can solve this problem
And if it still doesn't work, try uninstall and reinstall rlang `remove.packages("rlang")` `install.packages("rlang")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66782751/namespace-rlang-0-4-5-is-being-loaded-but-0-4-10-is-required)