# Problems loading caret in RStudio on AWS

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, r-caret, amazon-ami

I followed [the instructions](https://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/) to run R on AWS to solve local memory issues in computing. I would like to run [caret](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-93) but I am running into this error when I try to load the package using `library(caret)`.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.7 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.3 is required

I've restarted my Rstudio session and have uninstalled/re-install rlang but the issue persists. I am suspecting the issue is an outdated version of R because
`> sessionInfo()` provides:

- R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
- Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
- Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix the issue?

A similar problem was raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66782751/namespace-rlang-0-4-5-is-being-loaded-but-0-4-10-is-required), but the solution provided did not help.

Comment: What does `.libPaths()` show? Is this a corporate machine? Sometimes corporate setups have internal repositories, which may need updating. Can you paste the printout when you do install.packages("Rlang")?

Comment: Say no to "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)".

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "corporate machine", but I'm using my own personal computer if that's what you're asking. Readouts here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1m5Dv4MLou5gWVqRt1IXyCnPToyrjK9EiK78CaWljwgo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: R 4. should be enough, but it's common to update R and RStudio when you hit install problems, and it may work via a side effect. After that, `remove.packages("rlang")` then `install.packages("rlang")`. There have been times that I've had to manually remove packages. I'm curious as to what `find.package('caret')` returns. `pack <- available.packages()
  pack["caret","Depends"]` returns ggplot2 and lattice. A common trouble shooting package install tactic is to install dependencies first.

Comment: By corporate machine, I was checking if you had a managed repository like jfrog.

Comment: I don't think I have a managed repository, at least, I didn't knowingly create one when I created the server. I've updated the google doc w/ the requested readouts. Kinda weird, but after leaving it for a couple of days and coming back appears to have solved my issue. Thanks for your help!